# Conditional PNG Overlay in Custom Post Type Loop Depending on Post Type

Tags: custom-post-types, conditional-content

I have a loop pulling in two different custom post types.  I have that loop showing the thumbnails of posts.  Each post type used to have its own seperate loop and I had set up some png overlays to sit on top of the thumbnails.  I had a play button icon over the thumbnails of the posts in the Video post type, and a stack of pictures icon over the slideshows post type thumbs.  Now that I have combined the two loops I need a conditional statement to determine the post type and apply the appropriate overlay.

Here is the code I have that puts the play button over every thumb.  How do I change this to a conditional that would apply the btn-play.png over video thumbs and `<img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/btn-ss.png" class="play" />` over slideshow thumbs?

```
<?php $new = new WP_Query(array ('post_type' => array('video', 'slideshow'), 'posts_per_page' => '5')); ?>
   <?php while ($new->have_posts()) : $new->the_post(); ?>
   <!-- BEGIN .post-container -->
   <div class="post-container">
      <div class="post-thumb"> <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php printf(__('Permanent Link to %s', 'framework'), get_the_title()); ?>">
         <?php if (  (function_exists('has_post_thumbnail')) && (has_post_thumbnail())  ) { /* if post has post thumbnail */ ?>
         <?php the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail-ws'); ?>
         <?php } 
            else { ?>
         <?php get_the_image( array( 'custom_key' => array( 'Thumbnail' ), 'width' => 100 ) ); ?>
         <?php } 
                ?>
         <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/btn-play.png" class="play" /><span>
         <?php the_title('<h2>', '</h2>'); ?>
         <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
         </span> </a> </div>
   </div>
   <?php endwhile; ?>
```

Any help incorporating this conditional statement would be greatly appreciated.

*Just in case anyone is wondering about my code, which probably isn't optimal: I have two tiers of thumbnails so all the old posts where I hadn't specified a Thumbnail will use Justin Tadlock's "get the image script".  Also, the weird setup with the span tags is because I have the title and excerpt show on mouseover (with css, no js).*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
if( 'video' == $post->post_type )
    $play_button = '/images/btn-play.png';
elseif( 'slideshow' == $post->post_type )
    $play_button = '/images/btn-ss.png';
```

Then render the button with:

```
<img src="<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_directory') . $play_button; ?>" class="play" />
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks!  Just a quick follow-up question.  I put that conditional statement in the loop.  Could I put it in the functions.php file so I could call the $play_button variable in other parts of my theme as well?

Comment: Yes, you can put it in functions.php. Add `global $post;` at the top of the function where you put it.